# How do I refer to the historical data of different stocks in Pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

How do I refer to the historical data of different stocks in Pinescript?

I want to refer to the historical data of Apple and Microsoft

Normally, Pinescript automatically refers the close function to the symbol that is on the chart.

So how do I define that the close function refers to different stocks ?

For example:
Define that as an entry rule the closing price of MSFT, AAPL and SPX must be greater than the previous day's price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [security](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html) function for this together with the [History reference operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#history-reference-operator)

The first parameter is the `ticker`, so you can write the stock's name you want to get the data from there.

Then you can request previous day's close price like below:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)
apple_prev_day_close = request.security("BATS:AAPL", "D", close[1])
plot(apple_prev_day_close)
```